problems with the virtual item using image target
I'm using
unity 2020.3.48f1
vuforia 9.6.3/9.8
I create a image target in the scene where a white cube appear closely on the image.
The test through pc camera is good but when I install it on hololens2 ,the cube will be floating above the image and will move when I move with the hololens.the hololens view
I've tried using different version of unity and vuforia.
I tried unity 2022.3.25f1 and vuforia 10.22,
the test using the pc camera is still good, but when I install it on hololens2, the app can open but will not do anything later, nothing will display on the glasses.

Does the specified image target size in the inspector in Unity match the physical image target size exactly?

the size of image target in the unity matches the physical image target size, and the camera is in position(0,0,0)
